# Why is Gmail blocking CSS in emails?

Tags: css, gmail, html-email

I used CSS in my email and sent it out.

When I received the email in Gmail, all the CSS was disabled; however, when I retrieved the email in thunderbird or outlook, everything is OK.

How would I fix this?

Comment: Not only Gmail, even Outlook seems to be blocking non-inline or block css now. Both of them still accept inline CSS so the workaround is something like `<p style="background-color: #000">Hello there</p>`

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Gmail doesn't block CSS totally. It still supports inline style. Why doesnt it support style block, I've no idea. To have a good overview of CSS support in various webmail and email clients, here's a good one. http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Gmail **does** support style tags. Please make sure you put `<style></style>` code in the `<head>` section.

Comment: Gmail <b>doesn't</b>. I just tested it. It doesn't seem to recognize div tag also.

Comment: Technically it does 'support' style tags, BUT it strips all class and ID styles. It can read some elemental styles, but that is it. It is similar to me saying I fought a shark because I punched a shark plushie.

Comment: Email clients should ALL strip out remote css, javascript, etc. from the html email body and never load it.  This is a security measure that can be used to mitigate the Ropemaker style attack vector.

Comment: @Ruut: Thanx mate...this was helpful, putting style tag inside head!!

Answer (score 29):

I am answering it too late but this may help someone here. To be able to view your mail as it is in gmail and other email clients, you need inline style for each tag in your html, but writing inline css for each html tag is time consuming, to save your time use the builtin tool

```
http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/
```

Just paste your whole email template and you will get the html document with inline css in each tag. That much easy :)

Note: you can have your class and id in  class as it is.

Comment: When using this, if your CSS includes media queries, remember that they can't be inlined and may conflict with non-media rules.

Answer (score 24):

Stylesheets are one of many, many HTML features that are often blocked by webmail providers.

**HTML mail is a world of hurt** and it's not going to get any better — in fact, you can expect it to [get worse](http://www.fixoutlook.org/). Almost every feature of HTML is not supported in *some* mailer or webmail service. Anything at all modern is a dead loss. And of course there are still the text-only clients.

Unless you have endless spare time to burn uglying up your code and testing every last mailer, **forget HTML mail**. Just send a text mail with a link to a normal web page where you can be sure everything will work as expected.

Comment: Services like http://www.campaignmonitor.com/ do the dirty work of "uglying up your code" quite well, speaking from experience.

Answer (score 19):

If you could embed styles to classes and ids in an email, those could accidentally collide with styles used by gmail to display the application, or on purpose by someone with malicious intentions. In-line styles are local to the tag, and therefor leave gmail styles alone.

Google has to protect the user experience that it has created for people.

Comment: All/most other webmail providers allow style block. Doesn't see their own UI got 'hacked' by ill-intent CSSes.

Comment: They just have to display the mails inside iframes to avoid that kind of problem. That's what apple do with iCloud.

Comment: Or if they don't like iframes they can modify the CSS and put the message in a DIV. If there's a way there's a will :).

Comment: there a lot of ways to prevent this from happening I doubt that's the issue here

Answer (score 6):

Another good source of info is the [MailChimp EMail Template Reference](http://templates.mailchimp.com/). I find the Development section particularly useful because it includes information about what CSS GMail does support and how to take advantage of it.

Answer (score 3):

I have just been testing this and it does support inline styles, makes the code a bit ugly but you can get around it all.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ruby on Rails and ActionMailer you can use the gem **ActionMailer Inline CSS**. All you have to do is install the gem and it will automatically inline all the CSS in your mail templates. It literally could not be easier.

[ActionMailer Inline CSS on GitHub](https://github.com/premailer/actionmailer_inline_css)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css"></style>
```

Tags have worked for me, I did have an issue where all my CSS was not working because I missed a `;` 
It was a tedious process but I eventually found it.

At this [link](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/12_things_you_must_know_when_developing_for_gmail_and_gmail_mobile_apps-2/) #9 from here gave me the initial hint that it may be due to an individual line of CSS.

Answer (score -1):

Gmail blocks all external (referenced) assets - stylesheets, images, scripts, etc. This is to protect the privacy of the recipient. You can still include inline styles:

```
<span style="color:red;">Red text</span>
```

Comment: Frankly, I do not see why eliminating < style > block entirely will protect the privacy. I agree for referenced stylesheets/scripts/images.

Comment: @o.k.w A user-specific URL could be used that could be monitored to find out who "viewed" the email (by means of who accessed the style-sheet/image/script URL).

Comment: @pst: How does that have anything to do with < style > ? Could you not still use that same url in a style= inline style?