# Send RadGrid as quotation to the Gmail

Tags: c#, asp.net, radgridview

I have created a web page and send this page by email on Gmail. On Gmail it doesn't pick up any css classes there, but when i send this email on yahoo or any other professional email provider, it is working very fine.

I am using this css class:

```
   .tb_head
    {
        background-color: #da2526;
        border: 1px solid #71250a;
        border-top: 0;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 5px 8px;
    }

    <HeaderStyle CssClass="tb_head" />
    <ItemStyle CssClass="tb_cell" />
```

These classes are embedded inside the page.

And it render on the gmail as:

```
<th scope="col">Location</th>
```

Same case for the table rows...

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at this post. I think it has the answers you are looking for.

[Why is Gmail blocking CSS in emails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555171/why-is-gmail-blocking-css-in-emails)

Comment: thanks for your answer, i had seen this before. but my problem is with the Rad Grid , because the radgrid does not allow me to add inline styles in the header and item style, i can just add the css class.
any other suggestion?